# SQL statement runs infinitely

Tags: mysql, sql

This statement runs for a very long time and doesn't return anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT *
  FROM supplierdata AS s1
 WHERE s1.zip IN (
    SELECT zip
      FROM supplierdata AS s2
     WHERE s1.zip = s2.zip
           );
```

Comment: This SQL statement doesn't make any sense. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i just want to know how sql statement goes infinite loop and how long it will processed.

Comment: Hi @NimeshSoni, sooner or later this question will be closed. To ask better question, you can also explain what you are trying to achieve in the first place. This SQL is not making any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your statement is just running for a long, long time, because it is inefficient.

First, though, the query doesn't really make sense.  The following would be equivalent:

```
select *
from supplierdata
where zip is not null
```

I suggest you kill the query and build an index on `supplierdata(zip)`.  That should greatly increase the performance of the query.

In essence, your query is running the subquery for every row of `supplierdata`.  This is very expensive, requiring a full table scan of the table.  An index should fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a very poor mans count, so your query will basically:

1. for every row in supplierdata
2. query the entire supplierdata for my current rows zip
3. if i found something select it
4. repeat.

---

An easier way to achieve the same.
    select 
        count(1) 
    from 
        supplierdata s1
    where 
        zip is not null

Comment: i just want to compare 1 records with all others and visa versa.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the "this dont make any sense":

```
select * 
from supplierdata as s1 
where s1.zip IN 
(select zip from supplierdata as s2 where s2.zip between 200 and 300);
```

its equivalent to

```
select * 
from supplierdata as s1 
where s1.zip 
between 200 and 300;
```

And so on....just dont make any sense....it should be better if you explain what you tried to accomplish ;)

Or any condition that not references the parent query; you loop is not infinite it' just very long because first it goes row by row, just like @Nix says

Comment: your answer is right but i don't want to use 'between'.

Comment: what do you want to accomplish...i can help you ;)